# How can I test Punycode URL will display correctly prior to purchase?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, browser, unicode

I'd like to purchase a Unicode ([Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)) domain name (good.com), and want to ensure that it will display correctly on most browsers.

I found these links that describe Firefox, but it isn't as simple as typing an emoji and finding out which combinations display the unicode symbol (or not)

- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/tld-idn/
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/IDN_Display_Algorithm

What technique, app, site, or other approach will allow me to determine if a particular URL will display in not just Firefox, but other browsers as well?  (without having to purchase the domain)

Comment: Here's the same document from [chrome](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/idn-in-google-chrome)'s point of view. (Safari? Great question, but sadly I don't have anything near me for testing.) Also, your  emoji should be supported in all emoji implementations (cause it's been around since Emoji 1.0, see emojipedia [here](https://emojipedia.org/open-book/). Hope this helps! :)